# passing value in hidden field from one page to another in php

Tags: php, html, parameter-passing, hidden-field

I have a simple registration form.
I want to pass value entered in one page to other in a text field.
how to pass and access it from next page in php.

this is my first php page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: either you use javascript to access the hidden fields and pass it or use `$_POST` variable which means that you must enclose you hidden fields inside a `<form></form`

Comment: Thanks @ianace ..my text box is within form only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add hidden fields within HTML and access them in PHP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myFieldName" value="someValue"/>
```

Then in PHP:

```
$val = $_POST['myFieldName'];
```

If you're going to ouput this again you should use `htmlspecialchars` or something similar to prevent injection attacks.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myFieldName" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['myFieldName']);?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but its a text box..if a write hidden then it becomes invisible      <input type = "text/hidden" name ="" value =""/>

Comment: how to print $val? echo $val; something like this ??

Comment: then switch `hidden` with `text`

Comment: `<?= $someVariable; ?>` prints the value of the variable in the HTML text

Comment: What if it's not part of a form but outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this the form input in page A

```
<form name="" action="" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="myvalue" value="">
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

In  page B

In the page you want to get values put this code

```
         <?PHP
           foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value ) {
             $$key=(stripslashes($value));
          }
         ?>

<form name="" action="" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="myvalue" value="<?PHP echo $myvalue" ?>">
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

So yo can use or  attach variable value to another form do what else you want to do

Comment: Thanks @mustafa  foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value ) {
         $$key=(stripslashes($value));
     } is for ??

Comment: @rachel,  you will have to use or write down $var= $_POST['myFieldName']; for every single variable. This will be difficult if you have many variables you want to get. But  this way you can get all variables by using 3 lines of code.  And also using REQUEST you can both get POST and GET values.

Answer (score 0):

use following code, that should help you.

```
<form action ="formhandler.php" method ="POST" >
    <input name = "inputfield" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

on formhandler.php file yo need to enter following code to get the value of inputfiled.

```
$inputfield = isset($_POST['inputfield'])?$_POST['inputfield']:"";
// now you can do what ever you want with $inputfield value
echo($inputfield);
```

Comment: isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL